p-norm of matrix transpose
I know that $\|A\|_F = \|A^T\|_F$. But I cant find anywhere if $\|A\|_p = \|A^T\|_p$ is true. Is it true? How could I demonstrate it? Thank you!!

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

It's not true for $p=1$ or $p=\infty$. Consider the matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} -1 & 1 \ 2& 2 \end{bmatrix}$. Here, $|A|1 = 3$ while $|A^T|1 = 4$. Similarly, $|A|\infty = 4$ while $|A^T|\infty = 3$. Numerical experiments do suggest that $|A^T|_2 = |A|_2$. My guess is that, given the symmetry of the $p=1$ and $p=\infty$ cases, $|A^T|_p = |A^T|_q$ where $1/p + 1/q = 1$.

View $A$ as a linear map $\ell^p([n]) \to \ell^p([n])$. Then $A^T$ is the Banach space adjoint of $A$, so $A^T : \ell^p([n])' \to \ell^p([n])'$ and by basic functional analysis, $\ell^p([n])' = \ell_{p'}([n])$ and $|A| = |A^T|$.

Looking at examples is a good first step to proving/disproving something. It's not too hard in this case to cook up a counter-example. Take
$$A =\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 2 \\ 3 & 4\end{bmatrix}.$$ Then $\|A\|_1 = 6$ while $\| A^{\mathrm{T}} \|_1 = 7.$

True! Thank you!

In general the $p$-norms of $A$ and $A^T$ are not equal, though we can say that if $A$ is a real matrix then $\|A\|_p = \|A^T\|_q$ when $\frac 1p +\frac 1q = 1$. (If A is complex, then $\|A\|_p = \|A'\|_q$, where $A'$ is the conjugate transpose.)
My argument goes a bit beyond basic linear algebra, but I'll try to simplify where I can.
In functional analysis there is a theorem that if $A$ is a bounded linear operator from the Banach space $X$ to the Banach space $Y$, then its adjoint operator $A^*$ is a bounded linear operator from $Y^*$ to $X^*$ and $\|A\|_X = \|A^*\|_{Y^*}$. ($X^*$ is what we call the "dual space" of $X$. More on this later.)
This applies here because real matrices act as linear transformations between vector spaces, making them operators, and the transpose turns out to be the adjoint operator. $A$ and $A^*$ are adjoints if $(A\vec x) \cdot \vec y = \vec x \cdot (A^* \vec y) $ for all $\vec x$ and $\vec y$. The dot product can be written in terms of transposes:
$$
(A\vec x) \cdot \vec y = (Ax)^T y = x^TA^Ty = x^T (A^Ty) = \vec x \cdot (A^T\vec y)
$$
Thus $A^* = A^T$. (For complex matrices the dot product involves conjugates so we get that $A^*$ is the conjugate transpose instead.)
As far as what we mean by an "operator from $X$ to $Y$" goes, it basically means that it takes some vector that has a finite $X$-norm and turns it into a vector that has a finite $Y$-norm. For a real matrix, $X$ and $Y$ are just $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$, and since we're dealing with finite dimensions, all involved $p$-norms are finite.
One of the first Banach spaces a student learns about in any functional analysis course is $\ell^p$. This is the collection of all sequences $\vec a = \{a_i\}$ such that
$$
\|\vec a\|_p = \left( \sum_{i=1}^\infty |a_i|^p \right)^{1/p}
$$
is finite. Here, we are allowing infinite sequences, but any finite sequence is in $\ell^p$ for any value of $p$, $1\leq p \leq\infty$, since any finite sum is finite. Moreover, this is precisely the usual $p$-norm for a vector! So $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be thought of as a finite dimensional subspace of $\ell^p$, since all $p$-norms in $\mathbb{R}^n$ are finite.
It turns out that there is a particularly nice relationship between $\ell^p$ and $\ell^q$ when $\frac 1p +\frac 1q = 1$. Namely that
$$
\|\vec x \cdot \vec y\|_1 \leq \| \vec x\|_p \|\vec y\|_q
$$
if all of these norms exist. (This is a special case of something called Holder's inequality.) As a result of this inequality, $\ell^p$ and $\ell^q$ are what we call "dual spaces". For our purposes, this just means that they are the spaces referred to in our theorem about adjoint operators.
All of this talk of Banach spaces and adjoint operators is just to justify that the theorem above actually applies here. Now we are ready to put it all together:
Since $\ell^p$ and $\ell^q$ are dual spaces when $\frac 1p +\frac 1q = 1$, and since the adjoint of a real matrix $A$ is just $A^T$, and since $A$ is a bounded linear operator from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^m$, our theorem from the start of this answer says that $A^T$ is a bounded linear operator from $\mathbb{R}^{m*}$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n*}$ and
$$
\|A\|_p = \|A^T\|_q
$$
(If you'd like to prove this without appealing to functional analysis, I'd suggest showing that the inequality $\|\vec x \cdot \vec y\|_1 \leq \| \vec x\|_p \|\vec y\|_q$ holds for finite dimensional vectors and then try using that to arrive at the result. I'm not sure if this will work, but it's my best guess for a more elementary approach.)

Thank you!! Your answer was very useful! Where could I learn more about dual spaces? And, may I ask you something else. If Im looking for a bound in a sequence of $|M^T|_p$ (with increasing dimensions) and I know the sequence of the matrix norms $|M|_p$ is bounded by a constant, could I compare both of them to the Frobenius norm ($|M|_p \leq |M|_F$) to demonstrate that $|M^T|$ is also bounded? Thank you!!

@ignaciocrb for learning about dual spaces, any book on functional analysis will cover it. If you don't wan't to parse through a text book, Wikipedia's articles on advanced math topics tend to be pretty good as well, but it may require some work building up some functional analysis knowledge. Here's a link to a youtube playlist that covers much of the basics of functional analysis; it should be a pretty good guide to what order to explore topics: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yDdxFBcvSGw&list=PLBh2i93oe2qsGKDOsuVVw-OCAfprrnGfr

For your question about the bounded sequence of matrices, it depends on the size of $p$ as to whether that idea will work. If $1\leq q\leq p\leq\infty$, then $|M|_p\leq |M|_q$. So if $M$ is bounded by $k$ and $p>2$, then $k > |M|_p\geq |M|_q = |M^T|_p$. But if $1\leq p <2$ then you can only use this idea to establish a lower bound for $|M^T|_p$. For comparison to the Frobenius norm, look into norm equivalence (I'm not sure the appropriate equivalence constants to use, but they should exist): https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Equivalence_of_norms

$l_p$ space is not an inner product space unless $p=2$. What do you mean by an adjoint operator?

@user1551 that's a fair point. The usual bilinear pairing that defines an inner product on $\ell^2$ does define a pseudo inner product on $\ell^p$ for $1\leq p\leq\infty$ when $p\neq 2$. The adjoint operator is defined using this same pairing. This pairing is actually why Holder's inequality comes into the mix.
